# Define a count by foreign key relationship on a model using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have `ModelA` and `ModelB` classes, and I want to define an attribute on `ModelA` called `number_of_b_models` whose value is the result of the next query:

`SELECT count(modelb.id) FROM modelb WHERE modelb.a_id = :1 AND modelb.status = 2`

where `:1` is replaced by `a.id` from `ModelA`.

Since the query itself is so straightforward and self-explanatory it doesn't have to use the `func.count` construct, or any other SQLAlchemy construct - just to allow me to comfortably use `number_of_b_models` from an instance of `ModelA`.

How do i define `number_of_b_models` on `ModelA`?

Answer (score 0):

As a property on the SQLAlchemy model (`ModelA`) itself. This solution is not ideal in terms of internal implementation - using the `Session.object_session` classmethod. This can be replaced by `insepct(self).session` - but this is pretty much the same thing. This is obviously not suitable for mass queries (If you want the `number_of_b_models` from `n` instance of `ModelA` you will trigger `n` database calls). It DOES make `ModelA`'s API cleaner.

```
@property
def number_of_b_models(self):
    return Session.object_session(self).query(
        func.count(ModelB.id)
    ).filter_by(a_id=self.id, status=2).first()[0]
```